# Kubuntu 20 LTS - Wifi stopped working

Tags: wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

I have a problem: My Wifi suddenly stopped working correctly overnight (without me updating in the meantime).

Mon Laptop: MSI Modern 14 A10M.

I've had this PC since the end of July, and my WiFi had always worked until now.

But I turned on my PC one morning, and the wifi didn't work.

And when I do:

**sudo rfkill list**

I have this:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
```

Whereas before (when my wifi is working) I had this:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
```

Then then by doing this:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

My Wifi had started working again...

But sometimes my Wifi stops working again (and I have to retype the "modprobe" command lines each time to make it work again temporarily...).

_Do you know what could have triggered my problem please?

_Do you know how I can correct this problem please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We'll need to take a look at the system logs to understand what is going on with your WiFi connection.
You may run these commands in the background, or configure your journalctl to store the sytem logs. 
`$ journalctl -u NetworkManager -f`
`$ journalctl -u wpa_supplicant -f`
And general system errors:  
`$journalctl -p err `  
  
When the issue arises again, share the logs associated to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With this command :

sudo journalctl -p 3 -xb

I have this :

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2020-09-23 12:42:14 EEST, end at Tue 2020-12-29 11:40:27 EET. --
déc. 29 11:39:59 msi-14 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [^^^RP09.PEGP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/psargs-330)
déc. 29 11:39:59 msi-14 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._QD3 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x55ac, CPU2 Status: 0x3
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0x8047cb2c
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x1423a
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-55.ucode
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data1
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data2
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf low
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp2
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hw version
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | board version
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hcmd
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr0
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr2
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr3
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | wait_event
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
déc. 29 11:40:00 msi-14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
```

A laptop without WiFi is very annoying.

I would point out that my WiFi had always worked from the end of July 2020 until the beginning of December.

I would also like to point out that I have SecureBoot disabled in my BIOS, and that I haven't updated the BIOS in the meantime.

PS: For a try, I upgraded Kubuntu 20.04 to 20.10, it didn't solve my problem.

And when I boot my PC on a bootable USB stick, I have the same problem ...

Any Ideas please?